# python link values dictionary 1 to keys dictionary 2

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries. I have to match the values in the first to the keys in the second and then return the value found in the second dictionary. I came up with this so far:

```
d1 = {}
with open ("file1.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
       (key,val) = line.split()
       d[int(key)] = val
d2 = {}
with open("file2.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
      (key,val) = line.split()
      d[int(key)] = val

for item in d1.values():
     if d2.has_key(item):
         print value.d2(item)
```

I keep getting the error "too many values to unpack" and aside from that, would my script actually do what I want it to do?

UPDATE (Sorry didn't know I could edit my question!):
I my two text files, file1 maps a word to a number system, and file2 maps the number to its relevant category. The end result should be that the word of file1 is linked to its category which is found in file2. This is done by first linking the word to a number and then linking the number to a category. For example: Aanbidden (dutch word) > 12 > Cat. "affect". The lines in my file look like this:

file1.txt:

```
aanbidden: 12 13 14 57 58  
leven : 15
drinken: 23 56 
... 
(As you see each key can have one or more values)
```

file2.txt:

```
12: affect
13: posemo
14: Posfeel
15: Optim
23: discrep
56: money
57: metaph
58: religious
...
(In this file each key has only one value)
```

Comment: What line are you getting `too many values to unpack` on? Can you post the full traceback? (The most likely culprit is that your `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` have more than two items per line)

Comment: I doubt this will work.  you're printing `value`, but I don't see `value` defined anywhere ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, the following appears to be what you want:

```
d1 = {}
with open ("file1.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
       (key,val) = line[:-1].split(": ")
       d1[key] = val.split()

d2 = {}
with open("file2.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
      (key,val) = line[:-1].split(": ")
      d2[key] = val

for word, nums in d1.items():
    print word, "->",
    for num in nums:
        if d2.has_key(num):
            print d2[num],
    print
```

Given the files you posted above, it prints the following:

```
drinken -> discrep money
leven -> Optim
aanbidden -> affect posemo Posfeel metaph religious
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes both files have more than two items, that explains. Should I be using iteritems?

Comment: @JohnDoe: No, that has nothing to do with this. What does one line of your file look like (how many items), and *which* of its items do you want to use as keys and values?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Incidentally, you can [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) additional information into your original question. One good edit would be to show what you have on one line of `file1.txt` or `file2.txt`, and to state what part of that line you want to use as a key and what as a value.

Comment: I have two text files. One maps a word to a number system. The second file maps the number to the relevant category. For example "aanbidden" (Dutch word) should be mapped to "affect". This is done by > 'aanbidden' : '12' and > then '12' : 'affect'. The lines vary in length for example dictionary 1> 'aanbad' : '12 13 14 57 58 38'  and > 'leven' : '15' are both one line, each entry is basically mapped to one or more numbers. The numbers however are always mapped to only on category for example 12: affect, 13: posemo.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Could you please post two lines from `file1.txt` and two lines from `file2.txt` into your original question (using the `edit` link?)?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Also, if one word (like `aanbad`) is mapped to multiple number (like `12 13 14 57 58 38`) then how should you choose which category to use (`affect` or `posemo` in your example)?

Comment: My dictionary is much longer, so eventually each number should be mapped to a category. For example (aanbad) should be mapped to multiple categories.

Comment: @JohnDoe: In your code example, each maps to only one category. What *exactly* do you want the output to be? For example: what do you want the output of the program to be when given the two short files you put above (which I've formatted)? You can format code or output by selecting it and either hitting Command-K or clicking the button with the pair of code brackets (which look like `{}`)

Comment: Okay I edited the two small files to show all categories relevant to the example words. Basically I want the program to return 'discrep' and 'money' when the input is "drinken", 'optim' when the input is "leven" and 'affect', 'posemo', 'posfeel', 'metaph', 'religious' when the input is "aanbidden". Basically I want my program to return me the relevant categories to a given word. I hope this makes it a little clearer, as I find it quite difficult to explain in English>

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a great help!